# Hardware monitoring on AIX 6.1

Tags: monitoring, aix

We are currently trying to setup and hardware monitoring on AIX 6.1 so that we can interface it with our hypervisor, namely Zabbix.

Regarding the detection, I could make up something within a script using `errpt`

```
errpt -D -d H | grep -c "${current_day}....${current_year}"
```

One problem is that this command allows to detect the alarms that occured on a specific day, but does not allow a follow-up.

I could notice the `errclear` command, but it will delete the errors.
Shall I use `errclear`, will the errors disappear for good, even if they still exist on the hardware? Eventually will they be generated again?

Is there a way through `errpt` or `errupdate` to get the current status of an alarm ?

Comment: the error log is just that - a log; an alert won't be written there unless something causes it to. I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, though. Do you want a positive log to "clear" a previous alert? Do you want to avoid reporting on an error that you previously reported on?

Comment: @jeff-schaller. Thank you for your answer. Actually Zabbix expects to detect errors, but also to remove them. Basically shall a PSU be faulty, replacing it, might leave the alarm in the error db, but also say that the alarm is closed down. So yes, I am expecting either a positive message, or maybe more consistently a command that would show all the current issues. Not the the one that happened yesterday, but only the ones that a there for real at a certain time, or eventually get an update on an error that happened like jumped from state permanent to state fixed or info... Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If you want to implement hardware monitoring then better monitor also the (hopefully attached) HMC for serviceable events, and also monitor the system attention and fault LED. Regarding the error log, for one you can  provide start and end date to errpt so you don't have to grep. And even if you clear entries via errclear, they are still preserved internally so if you would send out a snap to IBM support it would still be contained there.